# Apache2 documentation

Tags: apache-2.2

I have to configure apache webserver on our production server to host two websites and enable SSL for one website. I am confused with the documentation found on the web. I am mainly confused between httpd.conf, apache2.conf and sites-available. for example, httpd.conf on my machine is empty.

Is there any good documentation for apache2 that explains all the capabilities of apache with an example?

Thank you.
Bala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those things you just mentioned are just conventions and choices that the distribution chose to use.  Not Apache.  Which is why you won't find documentation on it on apache.org.  From the sounds of it you're using Debian or some Debian based distro like Ubuntu.

If you look in the apache2.conf file you'll see that there are some include statements which causes it to source the other directories for additional configuration directives.

What you will find on apache.org is all the directives that are in those configuration files so I think you're already looking in the correct place.  There are some books available that may help you if you find that the documentation on the web is hard to follow as documentation can be be a bit dry and lacks some of the conversational bits to string it all together.

Comment: @3dinfuence I am using Ubuntu 9.10. Are you aware of any good books on apache for ubuntu?

Comment: I've never read any Apache books so I wouldn't feel comfortable making any suggestions.  But Apache is a pretty big subject.  There are a lot of modules some of which have their own books such as mod_rewrite and mod_security.  But have a look on Amazon and maybe someone else will jump in and recommend some for you.

Comment: Here's a good place to start if you're using Ubuntu.  http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/207 and http://www.debian-administration.org/tag/apache2

Comment: also: https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/serverguide/C/httpd.html